# Aplicativo não exibe AlertDialog

Tags: android-studio, alertdialog

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um app no Android Studio que em determinado momento instancia um objeto chamado `Mesa` com input do user. Para isso, existe um botão com o seguinte comportamento:

```
if (botao_criar_mesa.isEnabled()) {
        botao_criar_mesa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Mesa novaMesa = helper.criaNovaMesa();
            }
        });
    }
```

O `helper` no código acima é uma classe que faz uma verificação sobre os inputs recebidos. Caso não obedeçam uma regra, o app deve exibir um AlertDialog, e isso não está ocorrendo. Segue código do helper:

```
public AcertoDeContasHelper(AcertoDeContasActivity activity) {
    campoNumeroPessoas = activity.findViewById(R.id.nPessoas);
    campoValorMesa = activity.findViewById(R.id.valorMesa);
    alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
    alerta.setTitle("Oops... temos um erro!");
    alerta.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Entendi!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            alerta.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alerta.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Quero ajuda", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //TODO: implementar intent para a tela de ajuda
        }
    });
}

public Mesa criaNovaMesa() {
    Mesa mesa = new Mesa();
    int numeroPessoas = Integer.parseInt(campoNumeroPessoas.getText().toString());
    BigDecimal valorMesa = new BigDecimal(campoValorMesa.getText().toString());
    validaValores(mesa, numeroPessoas, valorMesa);
    return mesa;
}

private void validaValores(Mesa mesa, int numeroPessoas, BigDecimal valorMesa){
    if (numeroPessoas > 0 && numeroPessoas <= 30) {
        mesa.setNumeroPessoas(numeroPessoas);
    } else if (numeroPessoas <= 0 ) {
        alerta.setMessage("O número de pessoas deve ser no mínimo 1!");
        alerta.show();
    } else {
        alerta.setMessage("O número de pessoas deve ser no máximo 30!");
        alerta.show();
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe qual o erro e o que devo fazer para corrigi-lo? Estarei aqui para esclarecer quaisquer dúvidas.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Colega, eu acho que sem testar é complicado. Uma dica que lhe dou é você depurar e verificar se as condições para acessar o comando alerta.show estão sendo verdadeiras no momento devido.